# Uncaught typeError : projects.map is not a function in react js

Tags: reactjs

## i am trying to map through the projects but getting an empty array in the first render

```
import  { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteProject } from '../../store/projectSlice';

import {  db } from '../../config/firebaseConfig';
import { getDocs , collection } from 'firebase/firestore';



const ProjectSummary = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState('');
    const projectRef = collection(db, 'projects')
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getProjects = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(projectRef)
            setProjects(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        }
        getProjects()
    },[]);

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        dispatch(deleteProject(id))
    }

    console.log(Array.isArray(projects) && projects.length)
    
    const projec = projects.map(proj => {
        return (   
            <div className="card z-depth-o project-summary" key={proj.id}>
                <div className="card-content grey-text text-darken-3" >
                    <span className="card-title"> {proj.title}</span>
                    <p>{proj.content}</p>
                    <p className="grey-text">less than a minute ago</p>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => handleDelete(proj.id)}
                        >Delete Project
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return (
        
        <div>{ projec}</div>
    )
}
export default ProjectSummary
```

when i compile without mapping through the projects in the first render i get get false when i try to

```
 console.log(Array.isArray(projects) && projects.length)
```

and in the second render am getting the expected results

Comment: Have you tried setting the initial state of projects to an empty array ([])  instead of ('')?

Comment: thank you very much @Talha it is really annoying how a simple mistake could really cost your time